# Using sqldf and RPostgreSQL together

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, sqldf, rpostgresql

When using `RPostgreSQL` I find that I cannot use `sqldf` in the same way. For example if I load the library and read in data into a data frame using the following code:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host="localhost", user="postgres", password="xxx", dbname="yyy", port="5436")
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from table");                           
df<- fetch(rs, n = -1); dbClearResult(rs) 
dbDisconnect(con)
```

I know have the contents of this table in the dataframe `df`. However if I want to run a SQL command using `sqldf` I would previously do something like this:

```
sqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE X > 10")
```

This no longer works as I get the error message:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@localhost on dbname "test"
)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type
```

I assume this is operator error on my part, but I can't figure how what arguments to supply to `sqldf` so that it just focuses on the data frame and does not try to connect to anything else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Using sqldf with RPostgreSQL**

`sqldf` will automatically work with the `test` database in PostgreSQL if it sees that RPostgreSQL is loaded.  So you can create a `test` database in PostgreSQL and then use sqldf with that

or, you can specify the name of a different database.

See: [sqldf FAQ 12](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html#12-how-does-one-use-sqldf-with-postgresql)

**Using sqldf with RSQLite**

If you want to use sqldf with RSQLite rather than with RPostgreSQL you can use `sqldf`'s `drv` argument to force it use a non-default driver.  e.g.

```
sqldf("select foo from bar...",drv="SQLite")
```

or, you can set the driver globally using the `"sqldf.driver"` option.  From within R:

```
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")
```

or, another possibility if you wish to use RSQLite is to `detach` RPostgreSQL before you use sqldf and load it again afterwards.

See `?sqldf` for details.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and I detached the RPostgeSQL package, rerun my sqldf code and it worked fine `r detach("package:RPostgreSQL", unload=TRUE)`