# How to use sqldf with my local dataframes

Tags: r

Whenever I load:

```
library(sqldf)
```

I get this result:

```
Loading required package: gsubfn
Loading required package: proto
Loading required package: RSQLite
sqldf will default to using PostgreSQL
```

So, my issue is the default db selection by the sqldf library. I already read about how to change it to the local opened script, but the library description says

> "For SQLite and h2 data bases this defaults to ":memory:" which
>   results in an embedded database. "

What i need is just to run scripts on my local dataframes i am creating not any external databases.

thanks!

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28271239/1017276

Comment: Hi @Benjamin yes!! it works.. thank you.